# Why does the beginning of `git log` for the Bitcoin source on github say 'sirius-m' was the first committer?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Satoshi Nakamoto is widely spoken of as being the first committer to bitcoin.

Yesterday I ran `gource` on the bitcoin repo for fun and was surprised to see that the first commits were by 'sirius-m', or Martti Malmi.

Was there a previous repo in another svn tool and did Martti just do the first commit in git?

It really looks like Martti is the initial committer if you look at the git repo on Github...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source code was originally hosted in a rar file on Bitcoin.org. It did not use any Source Control Management. Later, when more people began working on it, one of the earliest developers, Sirius, moved everything to SVN on Sourceforge. That was later moved to the current Github repository and switched to using Git.

Comment: Are you sure that's right? The original email announcing the release links to sourceforge for the download: https://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2009-January/014994.html

Comment: @Murch Yes, that's right. Your link is correct for first sourceforge release. Read the last line here https://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2008-November/014863.html Files shared privately, have a look at https://github.com/fernandonm/bitcoin/releases/tag/preview https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=382374.0 & other resources on bitcointalk

Comment: Ah cool, could you please add the information from the comment to your answer?

Comment: @Murch Please feel free to edit the answer to what might be more relevant